# Vaadin components with stylesheets in .jar library

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a few Vaadin 22 + Spring Boot applications for which I'd like to create a .jar library with some components (mostly simple java components composed of standard Vaadin Flow components) that can be shared and reused in multiple apps.

Each component will have some dedicated CSS (global, not shadow DOM).

Normally, when the Spring Boot service defines its own components, such styles reside in the /frontend folder and the components can import them using the `@CssImport` annotation.

How should I package the .jar library so that the components in that library can use `@CssImport` to import CSS that also comes from the same .jar library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `@CssImport("./my-styles/styles.css")`, place the file in
`src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/frontend/my-styles/styles.css` of your
add-on, or make sure, that the file ends up on the class-path under
`/META-INF/resources/frontend/my-styles/styles.css`.

Source: ["Loading Resources/Resource Cheat Sheet/Table 3: in add-ons"](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/loading-resources#resource-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Oh, I looked at that page but missed the Add-ons table.  Will try it today and most likely accept this answer.